# adding pageToken to curl request to a Google Cloud API

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I'm sending get requests to this api

https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/occurrences?filter=kind%3D%22DISCOVERY%22%20AND%20resourceUrl%3D%22ENCODED_RESOURCE_URL%22

to get the list of vulnerabilities for a container image, however the full list is separated in pages, and modifying the request by adding a `pageToken` parameter is needed to obtain anything besides the first page. I can't figure out how to add that pageToken. I've tried adding it as a header and adding it to the url (`?pageToken=` or `&pageToken=` and different encoding combinations), but they didn't work. I can't find documentation on how to do this with curl.

Examples of requests I've tried are:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my_project/occurrences?filter=kind%3D%22VULNERABILITY%22%20AND%20resourceUrl%3D%22https%3A//us.gcr.io/my_project/tabulate%40sha256%3Ahash%22%26PageToken%3D%22token_number%22
```

or

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my_project/occurrences?filter=kind%3D%22VULNERABILITY%22%20AND%20resourceUrl%3D%22https%3A//us.gcr.io/my_project/tabulate%40sha256%3Ahash%22?PageToken=%22token_number%22
```

for these two I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Unknown Error.",
    "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
}
```

Comment: the pageToken query param is the correct one. Are you sure of the encoding? of the typo? https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.notes.occurrences/list

Comment: @perro can you give us your curl sample or error message that you received, for us to help you?

Comment: thank you for the response. examples and error response are added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using python's request library. for example this works well:

```
url = 'https://containeranalysis.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/occurrences'
parameter = '?pageSize=1&pageToken={}'
response = requests.get(
    url.format(project_ID) + parameter.format(page_token),
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"})
```

where `page_token` is whatever token has been returned previously by the API